# How to find the offending file for 'fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)'

Tags: swift, xcode, fopen, errno

I have a Swift/SpriteKit project with an `App Clip`. The app clip compiles on the Simulator (though it crashes when tested via TestFlight), but I receive the error `fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)`. **However, the offending file is not named.**

There are numerous SO questions on the topic of this error. But as far as I can tell, those questions do not address *how to find the offending file when it's not named in the logs*.

My question is simple: What's the easiest way to find the name/location of the file in question when receiving this error?

Thank you!

**Edit:** I'm also getting the following message:
`Errors found! Invalidating cache...`

Comment: Try `b os_log` in lldb and see if you get a meaningful stacktrace.

Comment: @Kamil.S Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I have no clue how to accomplish that. Could you explain it further?

Comment: In Xcode you have your debugger console where you can put commands into lldb(pause your program execution to be able to type lldb console commands).  `b os_log` stands for symbolic breakpoint for `os_log` (the current standard function for logging). Alternatively you can also set a symbolic breakpoint using Xcode in UI manner.

Comment: any progress with this? i've been running into similar using Flutter on iOS

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem in my Swift/SwiftUI app.  Could someone please explain in simple instructions how to go about pinpointing the offending lines of code.

Comment: did you find any solution for that ! I'm facing the same issues